# Formal fibers are normal

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, local-rings

Let $(R,m)$ be an [excellent local ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Excellent_ring). Suppose $R$ is a [normal ring](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Normal_ring).

I would like to show that

**the formal fibers $k(p)\otimes \hat{R}$ ($\hat{R}$ is the $m$-adic completion of $R$)
are also normal for all $p\in Spec(R).$**

Excellent rings are new to me. I could not show the above. It would be really helpful if someone explain the proof of the above.

Comment: Excellent rings are G-rings and I think what you want can be found in this [link](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/07GG)